# How can I make a cross-domain browser request to the Google Site Search XML API?

Tags: ajax, xml, api, cors, google-custom-search

This is my first stackoverflow question and it's a little obscure...let's see how it goes:

I'm having a problem with the Google Site Search XML API.  I simply want to use javascript to make an AJAX call to the XML API and retrieve the XML.  Unfortunately, this is a CORS request and the XML API response does not include an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so the request fails.  The JSON API does include the CORS response headers, but I need the XML API.  Is there a way around this?  Should I be using another Google API to facilitate this?

Alternatively, can I use script tags with the source set to the search URL and somehow get the XML from inside the script tags?  My understanding is you can't access the XML results in script tags if it comes from a cross-domain request.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

If the XML response does not include the needed CORS header, and you can not modify it you can only use a proxy on you server.

A proxy will not be affected by CORS limitations and for your JS you could now add the header or host the proxy on the same domain.

However now your server is making the request, not the browser of the client. All users request the data from the same IP. The regulations for using Google APIs that way are different.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I should have mentioned, the server can't make the request.  The server is not allowed outgoing access to the internet.  It's a Department of Education website and they have locked down outbound internet access from the server.  The request must originate from the browser.

Comment: More precisely, I have to get the XML from a browser based request, and then submit the XML as part of a .NET form, which will then go to the server.

Comment: You can host the proxy on a separate server that has access to the internet. Your proxy service could add the CORS header and you would be able to load it into the browser.

Comment: That sounds like a plan.  I'll probably go that route.  Thanks!